# sequelize gets all the data of a query without executing my condition 'where'

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

im trying to get some values from the database mysql with this sequelize code:

```
subSector
        .sync()
        .then(() => subSector.findAll({
            Where: {
                Enterprise_Evaluation_ID: 2
            }
        }))
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
           console.log(error)
        })
}
```

the problem is that sequelize get all values of the table and not only the data of the condition where.

any idea?

we recently change the project of server in AWS (change of elasticbeanstalk to other instance eb)

Comment: The syntax looks ok and I don't think it is caused due to server change. Try other where conditions for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Only issue I can find is , **`Where`** should be lower case like **`where`**

```
subSector.findAll({
    Where: {
        Enterprise_Evaluation_ID: 2
    }
})
```

**Change it to this :**

```
subSector.findAll({
    where: { // <--------- HERE
        Enterprise_Evaluation_ID: 2 // <--------- Also make sure the field name is proper
    }
})
```